# Colocar texto embaixo da imagem

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e coloquei uma imagem com um texto embaixo mas ao executar a aplicação fica assim,  o texto  do lado da imagem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.myapplication.MainActivity">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="280dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alan"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="297dp" />

</ScrollView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNome1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:text="Alan Turing"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alan"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="106dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

(Color.parseColor("#BABABA")); />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Como ficou a aplicação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ao colocar todo o conteudo dentro do ScrollView ele da erro, e a imagem sai

Comment: Esse layout não está claro para mim. 1º Não entendo porque dois Widgets estão fora do ScrollView que é Widget Pai, 2º Coloque todos os componentes em um LinearLayout e defina a orientação como vertical

Comment: Opa, coloca a imagem dentro de um linear_layout e o texto dentro de outro linear_layout (este abaixo do layout da imagem), depois só ajeitar o wrap e match parent.

Comment: obrigado pela dica pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de resolver o problema. Como por exemplo inserir um `LinearLayout` com orientação vertical. Veja:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNome1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text="Alan Turing"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cast_album_art_placeholder"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="106dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="280dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="368dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/alan"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="297dp" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: vlw man funcionou aqui obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Eis a resolução.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNome1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alan Turing"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/texto_autor" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]